# How to add delay on Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Shortcodes -->
                    <li class="dropdown mega-menu-fullwidth">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Vad gör vi?
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <div class="mega-menu-content disable-icons">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row equal-height">
                                            <div class="col-md-3 equal-height-in">
                                                <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                                                    <li><h3>Drift</h3></li>

                                                    <!-- Typography -->
                                                    <li><a href="index.php?module=service&page=capacity#capacity"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i> Kapacitetstjänst</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="index.php?module=service&page=capacity#communication"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i> Kommunikation</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="index.php?module=service&page=capacity#managed-server"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i> Managed server</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Övervakning</a></li>
                                                    <!-- End Components -->
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- End Shortcodes -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

I´ve seen a few other questions in this topic, but the don´t answer mine.
Is it possible to put a delay to the dropdown when the marker is not in the dropdown area. (Just to prevent clients to fall of the menu).
Thankful for answers.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `transition-delay` property to the dropdown?

Comment: Yes I have, I tried it on the class 'dropdown-menu' but i had no response at all. Is it maybe the original bootstrap css who prevent this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082267/how-to-add-a-delay-on-bootstrap-dropdown-hover it might help. Try using the .delay function